# when i try to connect with data base mysql through jsf i get error that no diver found

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jsf-2

/*java class */

```
package com.tutoria;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;
public class dbhandler {
Connection conn ;

public dbhandler() 
{
    conn = null;
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "1234";
    String serverName = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 3306;

    String dbName = "a2";

    try {
         conn = null;

        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", userName);
        connectionProps.put("password", password);
        System.out.println("trying to get connection!! :)");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + serverName
                + ":" + portNumber + "/" + dbName, connectionProps);

        System.out.println(" Connection achieved!! ");
            //conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception " +e);
    }

}

public boolean create_account (String table)
{

    return true;
}
public boolean insertplayer()
{
    return true;
}
public String  getid()
{
    String a=null;

    String sqlquery="Select * from student "+" where id='145' ";    try{

    PreparedStatement Stat1=(PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(sqlquery);

    ResultSet Rset=Stat1.executeQuery(sqlquery);
    while (Rset.next())
    {
        a=Rset.getString(2);
    }}catch (Exception e){
System.out.println(e);}return a;
    }}






/* xhtml*/ 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText value="#{person.name}"></h:inputText>
<h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
<h:inputText value="#{person.id}"></h:inputText>
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.idreturn}">
</h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</html>
```

/* i have added the jar file of connector but still it shows  no driver but 
when i run only the java class file it retrives the result without giving any error.. if anyone knows that help me . thanks for advances ..*/